What is this usage of でやる?

The context is a bit vague. As far I know he's talking of someone who  treated him and ran a shop and the main character is remembering this.
I'm stumbled on this use of でやる he seems to be handling him something which I assume is the check?

As you say

ran a shop

and the man is wearing an apron, I think your sentence can be rephrased like this:

うち（の店・飲食店）はこの金額（≈値段/価格/価格設定）で営業/商売してますんで

"We (=our shop/restaurant) are doing business with this price setting."
The verb やる can mean "run a business" ≈ 営業する・商売する. 明鏡国語辞典 says:

やる
❿ 職業としてある仕事をする。また、店などを開いて営業を営む。「農業をやる」「これまでいろんな仕事をやってきた」「店は夜八時までやっている」



handing him something which I assume is the check?

You're right, he's holding the check (お会計票・お勘定票), which is commonly used at Japanese restaurants and usually looks like this:


で is marking instrumental case here, so この金額で means "with this amount of money". やる here has the meaning "to live; to get by; to get along" (どうにか生活する). So together it means something like "We live on this amount of money".
